# So wide desktop on Gnome

Tags: gnome

My desktop has become so wide and I only can see the left half of it. sometimes applications appear on right half and I cannot access them.
How can I make it fit to my monitor? I tried to change some configurations in Appearance , but it had no effect on this problem.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a second screen attached, but not turned on?

Comment: No, there is no other screen attached to this laptop.  This problem happens unpredictably, I mean sometimes it is gone but again it appears abruptly.Also, restarting the laptop does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens from time to time if the system detects devices like a touchscreen input but doesnt overlay ot to the given display but interprets it as an extra Display.

If this is your problem - you should see a second Display in thr screen settings that could be turned off or be setup as a mirror to get rid of the "wide screen"

Comment: I turned off the second screen and problem solved, I had never connected a second screen! Thank you for you prompt answer.

Comment: could you accept the asnwer if this solves your problem?